# Visual Studio Hangs while connected to android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am using Mono for Android and quite often my **Visual Studio 2012** hangs, hogging an entire CPU, and doesn't leave this state until I disconnect my android device.
Am I doing anything wrong? Is that a known issue?
Using **MonoDevelop** for the same project get good results and is currently the way I'm debugging but I would really love to use **VS2012** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your experience is typical.

Please log your experience with xamarin via a new or existing bug on

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=Vs2012

I know there are quite a few existing issues there, that many have been there in NEW state for months, and that it may appear Xamarin don't care... But i've talked with some xamarin team members this week, and It's very clear that they do care and that they are right now looking at this area - so the more bug reports they have, the more they'll understand what their customers need.

Comment: Well it's 2016 (almost 2017) now and it's still an issue.